# Bold or unbold?

Tags: text-editor

Consider the following selections in a text editor:

[image]

At the end of the second line, there is an non-bold space.

For each example, when you click the Bold button, should it bold or unbold the selection?

Comment: Have you looked at any existing implementations (e.g. Microsoft Word, Gmail, whatever Apple's word processor is)? From what I remember, they tend to bold the whole line if the selection contains any non-bold characters, and unbold if the entire selection is bold. Seeing as it's perfectly ambiguous which way it would format it first (bold or unbold), I think it's probably most helpful to be consistent with existing patterns, if there are any.

Comment: Yes of course, I was just wondering if it was really the best option. Sometime this software inherits from old behaviors.

Comment: I agree with @maxathousand, most text editors will complete the action of "bolding" the selection before being able to toggle it back to normal. Even sites like Medium use that common behavior so I'd aslo suggest not reinventing the wheel here.

Answer (score 3):

The way that the feature is implemented in many of the popular text editors is to usually apply bold style to all text selected first, even if there are bold text selected already (unless all the selected text is already bold). I think having a consistent implementation of this feature creates the least amount of confusion, given that user interfaces used to work slightly differently when it was just command line based without other types of input.

There are probably multiple reasons why the feature is implemented in such a way, and why there has been on real changes since. Over time this has become the accepted behaviour for the feature. A user will understand that in your second example if the text doesn't become unbold when you apply the function, it means that there's probably a space character that is not bolded. Therefore, they can either choose to click on the bold button again.

Comment: I agree to all except one – that "user will understand the reason for unbolding in the 2nd example". I don't think we can assume that all users will understand that, because 1) The concept of a space having bold or unbold characteristic is a bit too technical. People who do not know how the character system works, wouldnt know. 2) Visibly, there is no unbolded text – and a space is sometimes hard to recognise when highlighting many text.   So if you want to build a perfect system for this, I think you could add an exception for 2nd case – unbold, spaces could be ignored.

Comment: Doing a quick user testing with a few users would help to identify if the suggested 'spaces could be ignored' is a good solution or not.

Comment: @Kish You are right in that we can't assume users will understand that all characters (including space) can have these properties, but the fact that when you just select the space and the same behaviour applies is at least making this known to the user. The alternative implementation of mark-up text editors is much more explicit, but like other types of keyboard layouts, it is not for everyone and has its pros and cons as well.